# Download/copy file from FTP server in Java

Tags: java, ftp-client

I am trying to make an FTP client from scratch in Java and so far I can connect to the FTP server. Im not allowed to use Apache to download a file, so my question is: how do I download a file from a remote FTP-server? I've now spent the last 2 days trying to find a guide but it seems impossible to find one which does not require Apache.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at `JSch`? http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: "From Scratch" meaning you need to implement the FTP protocol in java as a assignment, or are you free to use libs like JSH as @Zach mentioned.

Comment: ty for fast reply. but i have to implement it myself. No third-party libraries are allowed. That is the only reason why im not using Apache's FTPclient :)

Comment: I'm curious ... why aren't 3rd party libraries allowed?  Is this some form of Open Source paranoia?

Comment: I think it's ridiculous as well.. In my opinion Apache's FTPClient library works perfectly but i dont have anything to say since im a student :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite straightforward with an [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html). An example is outlined in [this post](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/use-urlconnection-to-download-file-from-ftp-server).

Comment: Nice! If you feel the answer is good enough, you can also accept it.